# Magento 1.9.2 products appears ok only if resave them

Tags: magento-1.9, product, save

The problems that i face in Magento products are:
a) Add to cart button does not appear
b) Image sort order numbers are not set

When I resave a product the "Add to Cart" button is appearing and Images getting order number "0"

How can I massive resave all products?

Answer (score 0):

I would try before to delete all the cache and reindex, but if you want to simply resave all products there are two things you can test:

1. Update attributes

   Add a dummy attribute (Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attributes) and change the value on the Manage Products via the Update attributes action. This not trigger a reindex so you will have to update the index after.
2. Programmatically

   You can make a script and loop over all products, make a small change and save the product:

   ```
   $_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
   foreach ($_products as $_prod) {
       $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_prod->getId());
       $_product->setDummyAttribute('foo');
       $_product->save();
   }
   ```

   This can be really slow depending on how many products you have.